# Add Custom Image on Rotating Mug gif

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am stuck on a script which is .... I want to add (Draw) Image on 3d rotating mug but html5 canvas loaded only one frame of gif...

I want something similar to http://www.howtoprintstuff.co.uk/pressiton/index.html

Here is 3d rotating mug Gif: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQi5dkXqj3XNXVMVXVWamFWY0k/view?usp=sharing

I am also open to alternative methods.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sop we can help you, can you post the code you have so far.

Comment: yes, [per specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#image-sources-for-2d-rendering-contexts:canvasimagesource-3), canvas will draw only the first frame of any animated image (except in buggy browsers and evil hacks). You'll have to either extract your gif images first (doable frontend, but not sure it worth the cost, so better do it before with other tools), or to use some css (place your canvas over an `<img>` element containing the gif.

Comment: Thank you for Quick Reply... Here is code..

Comment: html>
<head>
<title>#D Mug Preview</title>
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var productImg = new Image();
productImg.onload = function () {
var iw = 500;
var ih = 450;
console.log("height");
canvas.width = iw;
canvas.height = ih;
ctx.drawImage(productImg, 0, 0, productImg.width, productImg.height,
0, 0, iw, ih);
//start();
// outline
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.stroke();
};

Comment: productImg.src = "mug.gif";
var img = new Image();
img.onload = start;
img.src = "http://blog.foreigners.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Make-new-friends.jpg";
var pointer = 0;
function start() {
var iw = img.width;
var ih = img.height;
var xOffset = 125,
yOffset = 122;
var a = 129.0;
var b = 17.0;
var scaleFactor = iw / (2*a);

Comment: // draw vertical slices
for (var X = 0; X < iw; X+=1) {
var y = b/a * Math.sqrt(a*a - (X-a)*(X-a)); // ellipsis equation
ctx.drawImage(img, X * scaleFactor, 0, 6, ih, X + xOffset, y + yOffset, 1, ih - 605 + y/2);
}
}
});
</script>
</head>
<center><img src="mug.gif" height="430px"width="500px"><center>
<canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>
</html>

Comment: SO here is code.... You can check and the mug.gif image i already give you